# Discord bot snipe command "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to design a snipe command for my discord bot, so I went and looked at a tutorial on how to do so, but I always stumble upon this problem, no matter what I try to do to fix it. Is there any reason why this would be happening? The error that pops up is: "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined". Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const prefix = '='

module.exports = {
    name: "snipe",
    description: "Recover a deleted message from someone.",
    execute (bot, message, args) {
      const msg = bot.snipes.get(message.channel.id)
      if (!msg) return message.channel.send(`That is not a valid snipe...`);
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 256 }))
        .setDescription(msg.content)
        .setFooter(msg.date);
      if (msg.image) embed.setImage(msg.image);
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
};
```

`Edit: bot.snipes is defined here`

```
bot.snipes = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('THE WORST BOT IN THE WORLD IS READY TO FAIL AGAIN!');
    bot.user.setActivity('WUNNA FLOW', {type: "LISTENING"})
    
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'anmar') {
        bot.commands.get('anmar').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'mar') {
        bot.commands.get('anmar').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'fishe') {
        bot.commands.get('fishe').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'ran') {
        bot.commands.get('ran').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'help') {
        bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'snipe') {
        bot.commands.get('snipe').execute(message, args);
    }

});

bot.on("messageDelete", message => {
    bot.snipes.set(message.channel.id, message);
});

bot.login (botconfig.token);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overvfow! It seems like `bot.snipes` is `undefined`, so could you please provide the code where `bot.snipes` is defined?

Comment: @cherryblossom I have edited it to show that `bot.snipes` was defined in my main bot file.

Comment: How are you running the commands? Make sure that you are passing `bot` as the first argument to `execute`.

Comment: @cherryblossom I edited it to show how I'm running them, it's not a solid way to run them but I plan on revising it soon, and I'll fix that problem right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you are calling `execute`:

```js
bot.commands.get('snipe').execute(message, args);
```

Here, you pass the `message` instead of `bot` as the first argument when your `execute` function expects 3 arguments: `bot`, `message`, and `args`.

Use this instead:

```js
bot.commands.get('snipe').execute(bot, message, args);
```

---

Alternatively, you can refactor your commands to get the `bot` from the `message`:

```js
execute (message, args) {
  const bot = message.client;
  // rest of code...
}
```

```js
bot.commands.get('snipe').execute(message, args);
```